# How to disable a databound ListBox item based on a property value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

Does anyone know if and how one can disable items in a databound `ListBox` based on the value of a property?

Preferably I would like a `DataTrigger` which, when a certain property is `false`, disables this item (make it impossible to select) without affecting other items in the `ListBox`.

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="False">
          ??
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use ItemContainerStyle:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourPropertyName}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```