# Disable selection of an ListBox item based on binding value WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listboxitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable a databound ListBox item based on a property value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824543/how-to-disable-a-databound-listbox-item-based-on-a-property-value)

I have a `listbox` and would like to make some of the items in the listbox non-selectable based on the a field in the binding.

Ive tried setting the `listboxitem.IsEnabled` to false but this doesnt have teh desired effect.

Please could someone advise if this is possible.

Heres my datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridTemplate">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Border Padding="{Binding EditorRow.RightBondIndent}" Width="50">
                  <Image x:Name="rightImg" Source="mat.png" Stretch="Fill"  />
           </Border>
      </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EditorRow.MaterialType}" Value="Blank">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable a single item inside the listbox you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824543/disable-a-single-wpf-listbox-item). You can do it based on your binding property. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. Seems my problem was trying to set in the item itself as oppose to the containing listbox object