# update style of selected item in tow way mode

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a view that have a list view with data template 
i need to set style on the selected item 
but i need also when the selected item is been changed from the code it modify the selected item in the view

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="300" Height="50" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding List, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
                    <Grid Height="20" Width="30" >
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

there is a list view and textblock
i need when  the selectedItem changed it changed the the background of the selected item

here is the viewmodel

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Item selectedItem;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> List { get; set; }
     string text;
     public string Text
     {
         get { return text; }
         set
         {
             text = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Text");
         }
     }
    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set{
            if (value.Name != "Test1")
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                Text = value.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                Text = string.Format("Test1 was selected but the selected item is {0}", selectedItem==null?"null":selectedItem.Name);
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
    public  MainViewModel()
    {
        List = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item("Test1","Val1"),new Item("Test2","Val2"),new Item("Test3","Val3"),new Item("Test4","Val"),
        };
        OnPropertyChanged("List");
    }
}
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Item : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Item(string name, string val)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = val;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

note that when the Test1 Item selected the selected item didnot changed but in the view Test1 is marked as selected

Comment: What is your question? Selected Item color is not getting applied ? or Selected Item in List View doesn't updates your 'Item SelectedItem' property?

Comment: You say the view does not update the selected item when you set it in the VM, but where is your code that sets SelectedItem in the VM? There is none in the example above

Comment: ok the Selected Item is updated but its not highlighted

Comment: Again, where is the code that updates SelectedItem?

Comment: in the view Model there is a property is called SelectedItem
in the setter of that property it not allow the selected item to be Test1 but in the view the Test1 is still highlighted

Comment: Ah! So the behavior you want is that when someone clicks on "Test1" in the list, you want to PREVENT it from being selected?

Comment: Exactly, and thanks by the way for your time

Answer (score 0):

At the point your `MainViewModel.SelectedItem` setter is called by the view, the view has already updated its selected item in the list. The binding simply informs the VM of this fact. The fact that you don't set `MainViewModel.selectedItem` means nothing to the view.

You would think that raising `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");` would force the view to re-evaluate its selected item, but in practice this does not work. I assume is down to some optimization within WPF or to prevent cyclic binding updates. (Remember you setter is already being called as part of a binding update, and you are trying to update the binding again)

If you wish to prevent something being selected in the view, then you need to disable it within the view, before it gets down to the VM. [Here is one way of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824543/how-to-disable-a-databound-listbox-item-based-on-a-property-value).

Comment: i can't disable any item, lets say if user select an item there was a message box is displayed asking "are you sure" or somthing like that and if the user  click on yes then the selected item is changed and if not then it will remain the same item