# Skip first item of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have an ObservableCollection with a variable number of items. I display each item in a TextBox inside of a ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
              <TextBox Label="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Now I want to skip the first item of the ObservableCollection. I know that I can/should do that in my ViewModel, but I´d like to know if thers a XAML-way to do that. Something like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection.Skip(0), Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
...
```

Comment: As a note, specifying `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` doesn't make sense when binding the `ItemsSource` property. The control never changes that property.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It´s just an example that I put together from different pices of code, to show my problem in a simple way. I forgot to delete that part of the binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hide a `ListBoxItem` based on its index by setting a Trigger on its `AlternationIndex` attached property. You would also have to set a large enough value for the `AlternationCount` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" AlternationCount="2147483647">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Looks like quick and dirty. But that´s what I expected :). Works fine, thank you. But whats that AlternationCount, and why do I have to set such a large value?

Comment: Okay I got it. In this case every 2147483647th item would be collapsed. If I would set the AlternationCount on 2, every second item would be Collapsed. Right?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is 2 properties:

```
List<Item> _list = new List<Item>();

public ObservableCollection<Item> Collection => new ObservableCollection<Item>(_list);

public ObservableCollection<Item> Collection2 =>
    new ObservableCollection<Item>(_list.Skip(0));
```

Those observable collections will exists only in the view (binding will call property getter once, creating `ObservableCollection` for each property).

If you change `_list`, then notify what both properties are changed for view to update:

```
_list.Add(new Item());
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Collection));
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Collection2));
```

I don't think you can do something else in given case. E.g. [disabling item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1824543/1997232) or doing some other change to how item is displayed using item template is possible, but completely removing item... don't think so. At least won't be easy (own `ContainerTemplate` type to skip first item?).

P.S.: perhaps implementing own `ObservableCollection<>` which doesn't [copy list](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,60) (but uses same source in each instance) is a good idea, depends on collection size. Then you can implement own rules for iterators (e.g. property which will skip first item).