# Unable to disable textblock text in the itemtemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
 <DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="150" >
    <TextBlock MaxWidth="125" Name="name" Text="{Binding name}"      VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="0,4,4,4" />
   </StackPanel>
   <Button Command="{buttontext}" Visibility="{Binding IsAvailable, Converter={uil:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
 </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate> 
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">    
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Isenable}"/>
     </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I am unable to disable the text(Grey out) but as for the button is working fine.
Do anyone know how to solve this issue?

Hi Chris, i have referred to the link. i tried using

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding name}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

but it is still not working. have any idea on this?

Comment: Text (Not Grey out)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable a databound ListBox item based on a property value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824543/how-to-disable-a-databound-listbox-item-based-on-a-property-value)

Comment: Check your bindable **property** for **Datatrigger**. **name** or **isenable**?

Comment: Works for me, changing `Isenable` to `IsEnabled`. Provided, of course, the test data class I just made up has a bool property called that -- did you by any chance misspell `IsEnabled`?

Answer (score 0):

TextBlock doesn't support IsEnabled. The easiest fix would be to change your TextBlock to a Label

Comment: I believe `IsEnabled` applies to `ListBoxItem` (the target type of the style), rather than any `TextBlock`.